# AtTask API Documentation / Examples

Tags: api, attask

I am struggling with the AtTask API.  Specifically, I'm finding the documentation to be confusing and the examples to be very limited.  For instance, the API supports "Named Queries" but there seems to be no listing or documentation of them.  One point says that they are listed under "Actions" in the API Explorer, but I find very little there, and the named query that is used in the example "myWork" is not listed.

Can anyone point me to better documentation or examples?  I can muddle through by trial and error, writing all my own queries, but it would be nice to know if there is already a Named Query that does what I need to do.  For Instance, I need to get a list of assigned tasks.  myWork returns a list of tasks that have already started, but I also need the work requests.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no question that the AtTask documentation is very weak and that undocumented features exist. Very frustrating. One thing that does help sometimes is to call the meta data for an object.

To view a tasks meta data go to cl02.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/task/metadata

Then just copy and paste the result on this page http://json.parser.online.fr/

It's not the best, but I found a few undocumented features that way.

Regarding getting a list of assigned tasks, I would consider just querying the tasks object with a user ID set as the search critera. Something like

cl02.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/task/search?method=get&assignedToID=5419c3e90001c026e1b72b7014e8e694